# Function in C that converts an integer to a string

Tags: c, string, integer, return

I've been trying to create a function that converts an integer to a string and returns the string.
At this moment it randomly "mixes" the returned strings.
Please note that I intentionally don't use:

- sprintf as it slows down the microcontroller dramatically (clock 1MHz) so I can't use it;
- itoa only, as I need to convert an int16 to string that represents a rounded value of an angle, e.g. "359.9".
  Below is the fragment of code which causes the problem. Is there anything that could fix it?
  I've tried various methods - none of them worked... I'm aware that after executing this function loses the returned string. If the STR_OUT is not static then it outputs nothing.
  Thanks.

Code:

```
char *STR1;
char *STR2;
    
unsigned int16 VAL1 = 1111;
unsigned int16 VAL2 = 2222;

char *func(unsigned int16 NUM
{
   static char STR[6];
   itoa(NUM, 10, STR);
   
   return STR;
}

void main ();
{
   STR1 = func(VAL1);
   STR2 = func(VAL2);

   fprintf (USB, "%s", STR1);  //shows randomly "1111" or "2222"
   fprintf (USB, "%s", STR2);  //shows randomly "1111" or "2222"
}
```

Comment: please fix code to be at least syntactically valid

Comment: `void main ();` -> `int main ()`

Comment: `char *func(unsigned int16 NUM` -> `char *func(unsigned int16 NUM)`

Comment: anyway, you returned a pointer to static memory. there’s only one `STR`, and it gets overwritten every time you call `func`.

Comment: To me it seems unlikely that the shown code ever outputs "1111", because by my reading it reliably gets overwritten by the second call, with "2222" before output. Can you double check that you have provided a [mre] of code which really has returned "1111" at least once? (This is not about the missing includes, though adding them is also required for a MRE. And not about the compiler error for `;` before `{` either, though it needs fixing, too.).

Comment: Your code does not compile and the order of arguments of itoa is wrong. Please show real code.

Comment: Ok, it's sorted now. Thanks Ry: "anyway, you returned a pointer to static memory. there’s only one STR, and it gets overwritten every time you call func".